# Is there any way to record video on an iPhone 3G?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, iphone

My friend has an iPhone 3G, and is wondering if there's any way to record video on the iPhone 3G.

I believe the latest iOS update available for the iPhone 3G didn't enable the video feature and that it was only introduced with the iPhone 3GS. Are there any good apps which enable this feature? Ideally, my friend is looking for a free solution.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, and yes.

Here's one you can try: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/record-video-for-free-iphone/id376582359?mt=8

You can probably find others by searching 'free video recorder iphone 3g'.

You will also find some extra options on Cydia if your phone is jailbroken.